# Table not updating in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework 6 where user can update their password in `UserPassword` view. Password is stored as Session. I'm storing the passwords in mssql database. Everything is working fine but whenever I click to change the password, it's not changing at all. I look at my table & I can see the previous password. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserPassword(UserInfo pass)
    {
        if (Session["UserNAME"] != null)
        {
            var PrevPass = testdb.UserInfoes.Where(a => a.Password.Equals(pass.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Session["UserPASS"] == PrevPass)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    testdb.Entry(pass).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    testdb.SaveChanges();
                    Session["UserPass"] = PrevPass.Password.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ProfileView");
            }
            return View(pass);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Current Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>New Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Retype Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
        </div><br />
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Update" /></p>
    }
```

**Model**

```
public partial class UserInfo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string IsInfoMatched { get; set; }
    public string IsApproved { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string IsReportView { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code? If so, please I need a solution badly. I'm new to asp.net so I'm trying hard to master it. Your help will be a lifesaving for me. Tnx.

Comment: You have 3 html helpers generating controls for property `Password`! Only the first one will bind when you post back. Whatever you think your entering under the headings of `New Password` and `Retype Password` are being ignored. You need to show the model for `UserInfo`

Comment: I knew it. Please can you show me how can I bind all 3 of them? How can I modify the model for UserInfo?

Comment: How would I know how to modify it - you haven't shown what you have so far! Read my last comment again :)

Comment: Btw, the model is generated from EF6. I used database 1st approach.

Comment: If this is a specific form to allow a user to change their password, then create a view model to represent what you want - e.g. with properties for `OldPassword`, `NewPassword` and `ConfirmPassword` with validation attributes including `[Compare]`. But stop right now. Your code suggests your not even hashing your passwords in the database. Create a new project with forms authentication in VS and study the code in the `AccountController` and its associated view models to see how you should be handling all this.

Comment: I was instructed not to hash passwords for security reasons. I'll try to do that. Hope it helps me. Tnx.

Comment: Who told you that! obviously not someone with any knowledge of security

Comment: If I make it hash then there's now way to retrieve it. I've to deal with clients who aren't smart enough to use internet properly. So you can guess what I'm facing actually.

Comment: You need to do some basic study of how security works. You don't **ever** store and retrieve a plain text password. You hash it with an algorithm then store it in the database. When the user next logs on, you hash their password using the same algorithm and compare those result. If they match, then log them in. The lawyers will love you when they find out that you have access to all your users passwords in plain text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code For Change Password

Your Model will be

```
public partial class UserChangePassword
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword{ get; set; }
    public string ComparePassword{ get; set; }
}
```

Your View Will be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Current Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.OldPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.OldPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>New Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.NewPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NewPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Retype Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ConfirmPassword)
        </div><br />
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Update" /></p>
    }
```

And your action will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserPassword(UserChangePassword model)
{
     var user= testdb.UserInfoes.Where(a => a.UserId.Equals(model.UserId)).FirstOrDefault();

     if (Session["UserPASS"] !=null&& ModelState.IsValid && model.OldPassword==user.Password)
     {
         user.Password=model.NewPassword;
         testdb.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
         testdb.SaveChanges();
         Session["UserPass"] = model.NewPassword.ToString();
         return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
     }
     else
     {
           //False section
     }   
}
```

And am not encouraging to use Session for keeping login details. Use forms authentication instead. And using hashing password is a very good practice when considering security.

Hope it will work..

Comment: Hi, tnx for your help. Just one question. How am I going to store the `UserId` value from model according to my Session value?

Comment: Hi, tnx for this code. I just needed to add `@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.UserId, new{ @Value = @Session["UserId"] })` for setting the UserId according to view. I voted your answer. Tnx. :)

Comment: If you are using forms authentication, no need to use this Session, You will get user id by Simply using User.Identity.Name.

Comment: Which one is better & why?

Comment: Obviously forms authentication is the best way. we can do lot of thing on authentication using this way. Please have look on default MVC4 internet application, which using forms authentication. We can keep auth data in cookie as encrypted manner.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you made your view strong by bind it with model class, If so When you are clicking on update button make sure you are getting new password in your **userinfo** class because it is taking old password.Use Debugger to see what is in userInfo pass parameter.

Solution:
Add property for newPassword as well in **userInfo** class then You will get the result.

Please let me know if you find any difficulty.